# What are we calling this place?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, site-name

I realize that Stack Exchange isn't big on entirely branded sites, and that it takes a large amount of traffic or a very specialty site to give them a reason to give a site an identity, but I still think it helps to suggest alternate names.

For that reason, I'm asking if "softwarerecs.stackexchange.com" is the best way to call this site. I have a feeling it's stuck already, but if you have an idea, now's the time to say something.

Comment: Must admit I'm not a fan of "softwarerecs" - it took me a few goes to actually see what it was!?

Comment: @w3d I understood it right away, but it's very ugly to say.

Comment: Plus, it's a homophone of "Software wrecks" :/

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the formal site title "Software Recommendations" is not going to change (it *may*, and that's fine, but this is assuming it *won't*), I think we can use the following abbreviations / shorthand in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) and when referring to Software Recommendations on other sites:

- Abbreviation: `SR` (side question: are there any other SE sites with the abbreviation SR?)
- Shorthand: `swrec` or `sw-rec`
- SuperUsers might like to call it "The place where we throw all our off-topic questions" ;-))) (I'm only 82% kidding... seriously, I would worry a lot about the health of this site if SR were made a close vote migration path from SU, because a lot of bad questions would get thrown here.)

Comment: I like software.se and we're just ferry captains helping people find their way in the dark and cold "sea" ;-)

Comment: We don't need to worry about the SU migration thing right now, the policy is not to migrate stuff from graduated sites to beta sites.

Comment: Some AU users apparently considers to do the same.

Comment: @jcolebrand No please no general 'software' only in the abbreviation. 'Recommendations' has to be in there one way or another, or we get more off-topic questions

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea of something like "Software Sherpas" or something.

Definitely tho, software.stackexchange.com or recommendation.stackexchange.com is better than softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Seems like the opinion is for **software.stackexchange.com**

Comment: +1 for recommendation.stackexchange.com

Comment: Although, "software" is central to the whole site, so something as general as "recommendation" might not work.

Comment: I like that idea

Comment: "recommendation" is too general because someone may want to create a "hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com" at some point -- in fact it's quite likely to happen *if* this site makes it past public beta without being canned.

Comment: `software.stackexchange.com` is simple and straight forward.

Comment: Ugh, no. “Recommendation” is the core of what we do here. `software.stackexchange.com` wouldn't make sense: other existing sites such as SU have more title to it.

Comment: This site isn't for vacation rental recommendations tho, or book recommendations

Comment: What is wrong with `softwarerecommendations.stackexchange.com`? Except for it being long.

Comment: The fact that it's long

Comment: It was decided that labeling this site simply "software." or "recommendations." was too broad a label and potentially very misleading. If this type of site works, there would likely be other "recommendation" sites and the word "software" was simply too broad to apply to this narrow use case, misleading folks in what this site is about.

Comment: That's fine and well, but "software wrecks" doesn't flow off the tongue. If that's the name, then SR.SE would be easier.

Comment: @allquixotic, [hardware-recs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) up and coming

Comment: @RobertCartaino, Sad that of all the words, the word "recommendation" doesn't have a synonym. In any case, why is `sw` not an acceptable shortform for `software` in `softwarerecs`?

Answer (score 4):

I would love to see the sites name be `software-recs`. I think the enhanced readability offsets the additional character.

(In fact I read the current name to be `softwarecs`, which it isn't...)

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late to the party. But having to type `softwarerecs.stackexchange.com` (30 characters!) **everytime** does feel rather taxing on the fingers.

Inspired by `hsm.stackexchange.com`, I think it's great if there's a chance we  could shorten the url to `swr.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I'd prefer sr.stackexchange.com, but yeah, swr would be better then what it is now.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs, Good idea, though *some other* SE site [(cf.)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77052/social-relationships)  might try to claim that spot too.

Comment: That one is closed. The spot would be free.

Answer (score 1):

How about

## SoftRex

that constitutes Software and Recommendations altogether and is pretty small to fit in.

Its Quite Catchy too.

Comment: There are already, at least: "Softrex Consulting Inc.", and "Softrex | Software Engineering Pretoria".

Comment: @Unor We can be more popular than them ;-)